# process.env.API_URL is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, strapi

I built a project using React at the front and Strapi (based on Node.js) at the back.

On the client side, I'm trying to access my api url like so:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'
const strapi = new Strapi(apiUrl);
```

But process.env.API_URL is undefined. If I log process.env all I get is an object containing:

```
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
```

How can I access my api_url ?
I'm guessing there is a file where I should define API_URL myself?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app for the React app?

Comment: How did you set this `API_URL` envvar?

Comment: Does [this](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/configurations/configurations.html#environments) help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you are using create react app, Make sure you add the prefix **REACT_APP** like `REACT_APP_API_URL`. In your project src create a file `.env.development` or `.env.production` and add the your value with a key with the prefix

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do I have to rebuild the app afterwards for the change to take effect? And where in my project src should I add the file? In the root? Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver yes you will have to rebuild/restart the client server again when you add or change a value in .env files. If you are using create react app then add the .env files inside `src` where the App.js and index.js files are present

Answer (score 3):

In client side there is no such concept as environment variables. So, if you didn't do anything to solve this issue, it won't be defined.

Create react app has an option to pass environment variables from .env file. If you are using it you can check this document: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

If you don't have react-create-app, you can use dotenv npm package.

In essence, what dotenv and react-create-app does, will be declaring those variables for you in build time. 'Build time' here is important, because it's not like a server. You just build 1 application for 1 environment. You cannot use same build to deploy to different environments.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It is important to understand what is happening behind the scenes.
Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if they were declared locally in your JS files.
By default you will have `NODE_ENV` defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_`.

You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. 
Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. 
Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

These environment variables will be defined for you on `process.env`. 
For example, having an environment variable named `REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE` will be exposed in your JS as `process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE`.

Read more in [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) and in [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/environments-in-create-react-app.html).

Answer (score 1):

`process.env` is a `Object` and if you want add a property to an object.

```
process.env['API_URL'] = 'http://blabla.com:3000';
console.log(process.env);
```

**Output**

```
{ 
  ...
  API_URL: "http://blabla.com:3000",
  ...
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '1.34.0',
  LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if I have to define it each time, I can just not use it, thanks though

Comment: if you want to define it in a single file, use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Next.js Client Components: prefix your environment variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables